# sorted not taking lambda returning tuple as key argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to sort an array by several criteria. Python's [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function can take a tuple as a key for this purpose. It can also take a lambda argument as key. I've tried a lambda returning a tuple as key and got `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` and a tuple of lambdas and got `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. I am using Python 2.7.13 on windows.

Does anybody know why I get this error and how to fix it?

Example:

```
In [1]: message = {'tcu':1,'timestamps':{'device':23432}}

In [2]: message_array = [message, message]

In [3]: key = lambda message: (message['tcu'], message['timestamps']['device'])

In [4]: sorted(message_array,key)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-45bd2b89f64b> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted(message_array,key)

TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

In [5]: key = (lambda message: message['tcu'], lambda message: message['timestamps']['device'])

In [6]: sorted(message_array,key)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-45bd2b89f64b> in <module>()
----> 1 sorted(message_array,key)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.7, the signature of function `sorted` is `sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])`. You are passing a key function as a second argument, when in fact it's the third one. To always be sure you are passing a right thing to a function, use named arguments.

```
message = {'tcu':1,'timestamps':{'device':23432}}
message_array = [message, message]
key = lambda message: (message['tcu'], message['timestamps']['device'])
sorted(message_array, key=key)
```

Since `key` should be a function accepting one argument, it doesn't make sense to pass in a tuple of lambdas.

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I missed the difference on 2.X's signature ^^'. 3.X's `sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])` is definitely the first thing that comes to mind when thinking of that function...

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `sorted` function is not the `key`!! If you call it by

```
sorted(message_array,key=key)
```

it works.

It must have been a common mistake, that's why python 3.x requires the key to be passed as named argument